# How to debug a JavaScript switch statement error?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, url, switch-statement

I am trying to create a function that will run once every time a page loads.

The function will check what page(url/path) the user is on, then it will loop once through the switch statement and if any of the path names match it will then fire some info to an API.

I only receive 'no urls/path names match'. I know I nearly have the correct solution.

```
<script>    
function winLocation(path) {
return window.location.pathname.indexOf(path);
}
console.log(winLocation);
switch (true) {
case winLocation("stack"):
    console.log('This is a stack overflow page');
    // Fire info to api
    break;
case winLocation("google"):
    // Fire info to api if url has google in it
    break;
default:
    console.log("no urls/path names match");
};
</script>
```

https://codepen.io/bkdigital/pen/eQYQPL - Codepen example of code

Comment: Why are you using a switch? This looks like it should be done with an `if/else` statement. And what error?

Comment: What is the error message you are receiving?

Comment: That isn't the correct syntax, your switch is directly outside the function which you cant have in an iife expression like that

Comment: To answer your question: The easiest way to debug anything in javascript (as long as it is on the frontend) is to use the javascript debug tool in your browser. It is usually available when you press f12 and lets you set a breakpoint in your code and trace it step by step.

Comment: Have you checked what `indexOf` returns?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 function urlCheck() {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("href") > -1) {
       alert("your url contains the word in the url");
    } else {
       alert("Your not on any of these pages");
       }
    }
    urlCheck() /* autoLoadFunction */
</script>

--- I have got it working perfect in an if statement, just not sure how to make it work in a switch statement ike my boss wants :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the whole url, then you need to use `href` instead of `pathname` in your function:

```
 window.location.href.indexOf(path)
```

Also, since you're using a `true` in your switch, the response from `winLocation` should be a boolean as well, which you can achieve by check if it's different than -1.

```
function winLocation(path) {
   return window.location.href.indexOf(path) !== -1;
}
```

That would give you the result you want.

To check it out, just run the code snippet below:

```js
function winLocation(path) {
   return window.location.href.indexOf(path) !== -1;
}

switch (true) {
  case winLocation("stack"):
    console.log('This is a stack overflow page');
    // Fire info to api
    break;
  case winLocation("google"):
  console.log('This is a google page');
    // Fire info to api if url has google in it
    break;
  default:
    console.log("no urls/path names match");
};
```